# Difficult data retrieve and explode

Tags: php, arrays, explode

My friend and I are working on a few little web and desktop applications, currently we're trying to implement a statistic option to analyze which applications are most used etc. for this hes sending me a POST request which should look like this:

```
---------- website_application1 ---------- 
time_usage: 2h
other_info: XYZ
----------website_application1_end----------
---------- website_application2 ---------- 
time_usage: 2h
other_info: XYZ
data without key
----------website_application2_end----------
```

so I would like to extract and explode the data into the following

```
Array
(
    [website_application1] => array('time_usage'=> '2h','other_info'=>'XYZ');
    [website_application2] => array('time_usage'=> '2h','other_info'=>'XYZ','keyless'=>'data without key');
)
```

so each line between the delims. into an array element with the key. At the end of the block there might be some data without a key so a ":" which could be used for explode this. So far I only managed to extract the data between the start and ending delim. but not to name the array keys right etc and I'm out of guesses how to approach this right. Thx for any help in advance

Comment: The better question is why are you not using Json or Xml for this?  Like the cool kids do.

Comment: I cant json_encode the data before Im not having a proper array and the structure of the data at first cant be changed

Comment: ArtisticPhoenix is definitely right here, if a current way of dealing with data isn't working, you need to go with a better format. This is a problematic format, especially since different types of data could contain your delimiters. Is there any reason you HAVE to stick with this format?

Comment: `this hes sending me a POST` ask your friend to change it then.

Answer (score 2):

As I said I would refactor

```
<website_application1>
    <time_usage>2h</time_usage>
    <other_info>XYZ</other_info>
</website_application1>
<website_application2>
    <time_usage>2h</time_usage>
    <other_info>XYZ</other_info>
data without key -- what is this <data_without_key/>
<website_application2>


{
    website_application1:{
        time_usage: 2h
        other_info: XYZ
    }
    website_application2:{
        time_usage: 2h
        other_info: XYZ
        data without key: true
    }
}
```

Sure you can write some PHP to parse that, but how robust is that gonna be in the future.

Even in what you posted is a great example

```
---------- website_application2 ---------- 
time_usage: 2h
other_info: XYZ
data without key
----------website_application2_end----------
```

Do you see it?

```
---------- website_application2 ---------- 
----------website_application2_end----------
```

How about now `--web` vs `-- web`, inconsistencies will kill you trying to parse it.  And this is more obvious

```
other_info: XYZ
data without key
```

What if later you change `data without key` to `data_without_key:true` or `data_without_key: true` or `data_without_key : true`. It will be a mess to maintain.  There is a reason we hear things like `REST`, `SOAP` and `AJAX`.  There called standards because they are consistent.

For the time spent implementing and checking edge cases, you could probably employ one of the standards quite easily.  If not you enter the realm of data scraping and that is more art and luck then science.

Sure you can do ( Pseudocode )

```
while fread($line)
if preg_match( '/website_(?P<application>[^-]+)/', $line, $match )
then check each line - explode by : trim white space and build an array
etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

although refactoring to use a better data format is probably the *best* solution, as others have indicated above, if that's not an option, you can try crawling the text line by line and build your array like this:

```
<?php

$testData =<<<TXT
---------- website_application1 ----------
time_usage: 2h
other_info: XYZ
----------website_application1_end----------
---------- website_application2 ----------
time_usage: 2h
other_info: XYZ
data without key
----------website_application2_end----------
TXT;

$testDataArray = explode("\n", $testData);

while(list(,$line)=each($testDataArray)) {
    if($line[0]=="-"){
        list(,$key) = preg_split("/----------/",$line);
    }else{
        $usageLineArray = preg_split("/:/",$line);
        if(count($usageLineArray)>1) {
            $parsedArray[trim($key)][$usageLineArray[0]] = $usageLineArray[1];
        }else{
            $parsedArray[trim($key)]["keyless"] = $usageLineArray[0];
        }
    }
}

print_r($parsedArray);
```

Comment: I don't use `list()`, or don't find a use for it whats the `list(,` empty parameter for?  I like the `<<<` heredoc though.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix `list()` is not a function, its a language construct. It assigns each element of the array to a variable in `list()`. If you want to discard one element of the array, you can just leave it empty. Thats why you see `list(,`, because its dropping the first element.

Comment: @Havenard - ( secretly ) I knew all that about list, we'll except for the empty parameter, which I just seen in the examples on PHP.net.  But, thank you for the clear explanation none the less.  To me it looks like a syntax error ... I suppose it's just one of those `things` with php.  I would be ok with using `null` there though if that works :).

Comment: thank you very much for you effort I figured out a way to process the data.